# Is Onedrive Sync Client supported in SharePoint Online Libraries that use AADRM/IRM?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, sync, irm

Basically, I found an article on TechNet that syncing OneDrive for Business with IRM activated is not supported, now I am wondering, is it for SharePoint online Libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am getting mixed information, as per the [Secure and sync with Information Rights Management on OneDrive for Business](https://blogs.office.com/2014/11/19/secure-sync-information-rights-management-onedrive-business/) it is supported:

> We are pleased to announce that you can now safely sync your IRM
>   protected documents on OneDrive for Business. The IRM protection stays
>   in place whether you open file on Office Online or on a local folder
>   and continues to apply the settings even if you make edits to the file
>   in both locations.